Olympic Cartoon Showing Various Games
I remember watching a short cartoon as a kid (I'm pretty sure it was a short in a Casper the Friendly Ghost show) that showcased a bunch of Olympic sports. I think it included rowing, speed skating, cross country skiing, ping pong, and a few other sports, while the announcers went through each one. Anyone have any clue as to what this is
It was in English. I watched it in the early 90s, but I believe it was older than that. I don't really remember much. It could have had a slight parody feel to it.There were no identifiable franchise characters in it. Just non-descript humans. 

I remember several shorts or shows like that. Do you remember any more details about the athletes, like them being animals?

They were human (perhaps a little caricaturized). Everything was pretty normal about it; for some reason I feel like the announcers were British. None of the characters were famous or existed in real life.

Can you add maybe a little more detail? Like when you watched it, which language it was in etc?

It was in English. I watched it in the early 90s, but I believe it was older than that. I don't really remember much. It could have had a slight parody feel to it.

I think it might have been on the same VHS as "A Haunting We Will Go" (the Casper short).

I remember a Hanna-Barbera 1/2 hour which had all of the characters, like Huckleberry Hound, Grape Ape, etc, doing the Olympic type games. This would have been made in the mid-70s.

There were no identifiable franchise characters in it. Just non-descript humans. I do think I know what you're referring too though :-)

@Paulster2 - That would be the Laffalympics, I believe. (Going off of memory, googling on mobile is a PITA)

 
 
Could be "Sport Chumpions (1941)".
If you're certain that the cartoon looked "old" and featured human characters. More about this short:

Sport Chumpions is a 1941 Merrie Melodies cartoon. A spoof on sports
  champions and sporting events, "bringing you the lowlifes in the world
  of sports," including ping pong, skiing, track and field, basketball,
  baseball, football (at "Avery Memorial Stadium"), auto racing,
  swimming and billiards.

~ Synopsis from the Looney Toons Wikia; Stills used are video screenshots
Watch it here to confirm.

I'm pretty sure this is it. I'll confirm when I get a chance. Thanks :-)

Yes thank you! I guess my memory is going a little, but it was great to see that again.

There is a similar cartoon via Disney with Goofy performing the events (and failing spectacularly in each one), both summer and winter sports versions if I recall correctly.
